# RequireJS sometimes fails to load jQuery

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My project structure looks like this

```
root/
  lib/
  js/
```

In my js folder I have a require-config file which references javascript-files in the lib directory. Like so:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: ["../lib/jquery/dist/jquery"],
    }
});
```

Initiated in view like so:

```
<script data-main="js/require-config" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.1/require.min.js"></script>
<script>require(["viewModels/searchViewModel"]);</script>
```

And this is how my searchViewModel looks like (omitted code inside function), generated from typescript:

```
define(["require", "exports", "jquery"], function (require, exports, $) {
    "use strict";
    var SearchViewModel = (function () {
        function SearchViewModel() {
        }
        return SearchViewModel;
    }
});
```

For most of the time, there seems to be no problem finding the correct file. Occasionally though, it is looking for the jquery file in /js/jquery.js which will cause the browser to throw a 404 for http://localhost/js/jquery.js.

Am I doing something wrong in the require config? And how come it works sometimes and sometimes not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `data-main` to load your RequireJS configuration. The reason it works intermittently is because `data-main` causes RequireJS to load named script *asynchronously*. So by the time `require(["viewModels/searchViewModel"]);` executes, your configuration has not necessarily been loaded.

Using `data-main` to load configuration is safe only when *all* the code that depends on this configuration is loaded through the same file you pass to `data-main`. This could be because you've built a bundle that contains all the  modules of your app plus the configuration, or because you use only `deps` in the configuration to load modules after the configuration is loaded.

Your case is not safe because you have code *outside* the module you load through `data-main` that depend on the configuration being loaded.

Split your `script` like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.1/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/require-config.js"></script>
```