# RequireJS sporadically throws exceptions when requiring jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, requirejs

I'm using typescript in my .net core application and I'm managing my scripts with requirejs.

So there's a button in my footer that when click it, it calls my .net core action, receives data and shows the result on the surface.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">
    <footer>
        <a id="debug_button" title="Show/hide debugging">
            <span class="fas fa-code"></span>
        </a>

    </footer>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/js/config"></script>

<script>
    require(['../ts/debugarea'],
        function(debugarea) {
            debugarea.buildDebugArea(false);

            $("#debug_button").click(function() {
                debugarea.buildDebugArea(true);
            });
        });
</script>
```

the js/config.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "../lib/jquery/dist/jquery",
        bootstrap: "../lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap",
        backbone: "../lib/backbone/backbone",
        underscore: "../lib/underscore/underscore",
        modernizr: "../lib/modernizr/src/Modernizr",
        unobtrusiveajax: "../lib/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min",
        CookieMonster: "../ts/http/CookieMonster",
        debugarea: "../ts/debugarea",
        signalr: "../lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr"
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: ["jquery", "underscore"],
        bootstrap: ["jquery"],
        Modernizr: {
            exports: 'Modernizr',
        },
        unobtrusiveajax: ["jquery"],
        debugarea:['jquery']
    }
});
```

and the debugarea.ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

console.log("debugarea");
console.log($);

export function buildDebugArea(switchCookie): void {
    let currentCookieValue: string = CookieMonster.CookieMonster.getCookie('debugarea');

    if (switchCookie) {
        if (currentCookieValue === "")
            CookieMonster.CookieMonster.setCookie('debugarea', "true", 1);
        else
            return clearDebugArea();
    } else if (currentCookieValue === "")
        return clearDebugArea();

    $('#debuginfo').append($('<div id="cookieinfo"></div>'));

    getCookies();
    let debugbuttonIcon: JQuery<HTMLElement> = $('#debug_button > span');
    if (debugbuttonIcon.length == 0) return;

    debugbuttonIcon.addClass("bg-dark text-white");
}
```

90% of it works and my console output from debugarea.ts is

```
debugarea.ts:3 debugarea
debugarea.ts:4 ƒ ( selector, context ) {

        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
        return new jQuery…
```

sporadically, just when reloading the browser-tab, I receive these errors here:

```
require.js:1961 GET http://localhost:58006/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: ../ts/debugarea
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738)
```

when reloading next time, it works again.
Any idea what is going wrong here? Did I miss something?

I'm using jQuery 3.1.1 and RequireJS 2.3.5

edit: here two screenshot from debugger (network tab) - perhaps it helps.

1. when it throws exceptions:

[image]

2. when it works correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/js/config"></script>
```

I believe your issue is here. You are specifying `data-main` to load `require.js` and thus causes your script to load asynchronously. Since this script may sometimes load out of order, there is a chance other scripts load before or after it, and that can potentially break dependencies.

> Using `data-main` to load configuration is safe only when all the code that depends on this configuration is loaded through the same file you pass to data-main. This could be because you've built a bundle that contains all the modules of your app plus the configuration [...]

From: [RequireJS sometimes fails to load jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408516/requirejs-sometimes-fails-to-load-jquery)

Recommended solution:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/config"></script>

<script>
require(['../ts/debugarea'],
    function(debugarea) {
        debugarea.buildDebugArea(false);

        $("#debug_button").click(function() {
            debugarea.buildDebugArea(true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Loading the scripts separately (and in order) should ensure that all dependencies are properly met when the page loads.

Comment: I thought so, too - but after debugging, the config seems to be loaded completely: the exceptions still appear sometimes. I guess, there's something wrong with my config.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger it's not whether it's loaded fully or not, it's the order of the script execution. Look at the waterfalls in you dev tools photos. Notice how in the working screenshot the config file is fully loaded before jQuery is loaded whereas in the broken screenshot the config hasn't finished loading when jQuery fails.

Comment: I see, I'm going to try your solution..

Comment: the cdn script doesn't work somehow.. but by using mine, it works. I'm not very amused by losing the asynchronous part. Nevertheless it works and perhaps I'm going to find a better solution one day.. thanks! - (I cannot award the bounty before 24h)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger technically you're not really losing it since your config script wouldn't be called until after require loaded anyways. It should still load in roughly the same same time since require will load the extra scripts async. That all said, I'd suggest looking at webpack or rollup (and Babel for poly fills) in the future and building your JavaScript files ahead of time instead of relying on require directly. Glad you got it all worked out for now though! :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Just noticed I accidentally copied the link for the Node.js version of require and not the browser version, so makes sense that it wouldn't work haha. I updated the code snippet just in case someone in the future needs to copy paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you required **script path** not name in the map then jquery not loaded before script call.

```
<script>
    require(['debugarea'],
        function(debugarea) {
            debugarea.buildDebugArea(false);

            $("#debug_button").click(function() {
                debugarea.buildDebugArea(true);
            });
        });
</script>
```

**shim config**

```
shim: {
        ...
        '../ts/debugarea': {
             'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
```

Update 1:
When I working with **shim**, sometime it not working correctly, then I use require to fix that issue. You can required jquery into require script

```
<script>
        require(['jquery','debugarea'],
            function($, debugarea) {
                debugarea.buildDebugArea(false);

                $("#debug_button").click(function() {
                    debugarea.buildDebugArea(true);
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Update: Out of scope of the answer, I need more info such as can you post tiny code to **https://jsfiddle.net/**

Comment: when I use the path, the error still appears, thank you anyway..

Comment: I updated my answer I hope this help **update 1*. If not help then sorry.

Comment: Neither helps... :D - I saw, you are using `'../ts/debugarea': { 'deps': ['jquery']}` instead of `'../ts/debugarea': ['jquery']`. Does this make any difference whether I'm using just `['jquery']` or I'm using `{deps:['jquery']}`?

Comment: When I working with shim, sometime it not working correctly, then I use require to fix that issue. **deps** is the newest version for shim config.  these seem to like.

Comment: it seems, after changing that from a plain list to that `deps:[...]` this now works just fine.

Comment: My Comment missed: **these are like the same.**

Comment: okay, the exceptions just appeared again.. sad.. i thought it's okay now...

Comment: Can you please create a unit function in jsfiddle?,